# Too many dhcpcd "router available" message in the syslog

Tags: dhcp

I'm visiting my relative's house during this holiday. I bought my Raspberry Pi 3 and other gadgets. The Pi is a media server and a wifi router to share the internet in the guest room.

Everything is working, but I noticed syslog kept recording the following messages in the `/var/log/syslog` on every few seconds. Following is just an excerpt but the actual number of the records was nearly 100k since the Christmas Eve.

```
...
Dec 30 20:50:20 RPi-Dev dhcpcd[591]: wlan0: fe80::4270:9ff:fef7:74d7 router available
Dec 30 20:50:23 RPi-Dev dhcpcd[591]: wlan0: fe80::4270:9ff:fef7:74d7 router available
Dec 30 20:50:27 RPi-Dev dhcpcd[591]: wlan0: fe80::4270:9ff:fef7:74d7 router available
Dec 30 20:50:32 RPi-Dev dhcpcd[591]: wlan0: fe80::4270:9ff:fef7:74d7 router available
Dec 30 20:50:41 RPi-Dev dhcpcd[591]: wlan0: fe80::4270:9ff:fef7:74d7 router available
..
```

I could find a similiar problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273818/can-i-stop-ipv6-router-advertisement-filling-syslog-without-disabling-ipv6) and added a setting that suppresses the message in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` as following.

```
:msg, contains, "router available" ~
```

Now, `rsyslog`stopped recording the message. However, I'm not comfortable with it, and I'd like to fix the cause. Could someone explain to me what might be causing it, what I should check and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Edit /etc/dhcpcd.conf and add a single line to the bottom of the file "noipv6rs" - that **does** seem to stop the lot by stopping IPV6 route solicitations. I've added nodhcp6 as well to be sure - this alone doesn't stop dhcpcd reporting a friendly, helpful router...

Comment: So should you add that line to the file and reset the RPi? Or does it have an immediate effect?